# How do I find delegates, anonymous methods and lambda expressions in my code?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, anonymous-function, edit-and-continue

I like Edit-and-Continue very much, so much that I want to find all kinds of things that prevent it from working and move them away into separate methods, change to regular methods or something.

Problem is I can't easily locate them in my code.

Is there some functionality in Visual Studio that allows to browse all those things, or should I just use search with wildcards, or something else completely?

Comment: I'm not really sure, if building architecture of your program basing on ease of debugging is such a good idea.

Comment: It is, it's an XNA game. And I'm learning programming, so I'd like to speed things up a bit. Leave the safe and high-quality approaches for the release build.

Comment: It's easier for me to make edits on-the-fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lambdas, find (ctrl+f) all `=>` in your code.
To delegates, search for all `delegate`, `Func`, `Action`, `Predicate`.